# Get M at a point

Tags: arcobjects

I am trying to transfer the Measure values from an old feature to a newer one. Frequently the measures on the new feature have just been reversed.

I am using `IMSegmentation3.GetPointsAtM` to get the point where the measure occurs on the old polyline. I am then using `IPolyline4.QueryPointAndDistance` to find the distance along the new line of the old point.

The problem lies with assuming a distance = a measure value. I am finding that they don't agree and the distance I get is often more than 300m out.

How can I find the Measure at a point on a measured polyline?

Comment: Don't forget to take the [Tour].  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Comment: You don't explain what your data represents so that disparity could be quite genuine if you are comparing a channelised river to a natural meandering river channel. Suggest you add more information, including code and a diagram to your question as suggested by @PolyGeo.